# Digit ranges in Antlr4? Should lexer rules be unambiguous in Antlr4?

Tags: grammar, antlr4, lexer

Should lexer rules be unambiguous in Antlr4?

Suppose I would like to parse dates and defined

```
hour: DIGIT09 | (DIGIT1 DIGIT09) | (DIGIT2 DIGIT04);

month: DIGIT19 | (DIGIT1 DIGIT02);

DIGIT12: '1'..'2';

DIGIT1: '1';

DIGIT2: '2';

DIGIT19: '1'..'9';

DIGIT09: '0'..'9';

DIGIT04: '0'..'4';

DIGIT04: '0'..'2';
```

Here I defined digit ranges in lexer. But looks like it doesn't work, since they are ambiguous.

Can I define ranges in parser instead of lexer?

Answer (score 1):

This type of validation is best performed in a listener or visitor which executes after a parse tree is created. Start with just a number:

```
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
```

Then define `hour` and `month` based on this:

```
hour : NUMBER;
month : NUMBER;
```

After you have a parse tree, implement `enterHour` and `enterMonth` to validate that the `NUMBER` contained in each is valid.

This approach yields the best combination of error recovery and error reporting in the event the user enters incorrect input.

Comment: Do I have a ready value on `enter`? Shouldn't I do this in `exit`? How would I report test result?